# Does reputation do more than what we think?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

Am I here to get reputation and getting control over sites.

I am talking about the reputation and the privileges we are getting by questioning, answering and commenting. I am keep getting new privileges and thinking what would I get after the last privilege I get in 4000 reputation [source](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Is the reputation to get trust and gravity on questions and answers of popular user or it is more than what I am saying.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237 and http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of note, it's not like once you hit 4,000 rep there are no privileges left to achieve; the current reputation levels are only the levels for a *beta* site.  On a graduated Stack Exchange site, the same privileges require much higher levels with the last privilege achieved at 20,000 rep.

And just because the *current* set of privileges caps at 20k does not mean that they will stay that way forever.  There are numerous discussions and feature-requests on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) regarding possible new privileges for the 20k+ crowd, or for existing privileges to scale according to reputation (e.g. extra close votes or flags for every x000 reputation); I have no clue which if any of these features are under consideration (or have even been implemented without my knowledge) but Stack Exchange is constantly under development.

Beyond that, it's basically just a form of [gamification](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification).  Many people are more inclined to keep participating so long as there's some form of <strike>arbitrary</strike> score that tracks their progress and shows that their contributions are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but why did you strike 'arbitrary'? to denote negation or uncertainty?

Comment: @infatuated it's because the subtlety and subtext that strikethrough humor provides both amuses and satisfies me in ways that not including it would not.